# Compilation Error when compiling Objective C program

Tags: objective-c

I am Trying to run a Objective C program on GNUStep , but it is giving the following error :

C :/gnustep/bin/.../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/.../.../mingw32/bin/ld.exe :cannot find lobj

collect : ld returned 1 exit status

Tried the following command :

gcc -o helloworld helloworld.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString

Any posssible fixes ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run objective c code in terminal or cmd using gcc compiler than refer this link,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_environment_setup.htm

It provides step by step information for running objective c program in cmd and terminal.